# [Breadcrumbs]Missing argument 3 for DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider::{closure}()

Tags: php, package, laravel-5.3, breadcrumbs, laravel-blade

Yeah I'm trying to use package Breadcrumbs from davejamemiller, already install and it works,  but besides that im having trouble like this :

1. Example : I have   Home/User List/User Detail , in "User Detail" which is it sends URI : "user/view/{id}" and i already solve it, but also in User Detail it will show User's Product which is find by "ProductID" , so in code i type like :

Home -> User List -> User Detail -> Expert's View Product Detail the code is :

```
Breadcrumbs::register('product.detail', function($breadcrumbs, $user, $product)
{
    $breadcrumbs->parent('user.detail', $user);
    $breadcrumbs->push('Expert\'s View Product Detail', route('product.detail', $product));
});
```

it if i run it the error message says : 
[Missing argument 3 for DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider::{closure}()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmpJa.png)

by the way this is the breadcrumbs for User Detail :
//Home -> User List -> User Detail

```
Breadcrumbs::register('user.detail', function($breadcrumbs, $user)
{
    $breadcrumbs->parent('user.list');
    $breadcrumbs->push('User Detail', route('user.detail', $user));
});
```

Can anybody help me figure it out :( ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the render call with `Breadcrumb::render()` in your Blade template:

It seems you're not passing a `$product` object:

```
{!! Breadcrumbs::render('product.detail', $user, $product) !!}
                                                 ^^^^^^^^ Did you forget this one?
```

And try passing object ids instead of the whole object as argument to the route helper:

```
route('product.detail', $product->id)
route('user.detail', $user->id)
```

Comment: hi @Baik Ho, in my Blade Template i only use the render call with Breadcrumb::render() only, and i already add on : 
route('product.detail', $product->id)
route('user.detail', $user->id)

still didnt work . :(